# tsql: How to retrieve the last date of each month between given date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two date for example 08/08/2013 and 11/11/2013 and I need last date of each month starting from August to November in a table so that i can iterate over the table to pick those dates individually.

I know how to pick last date for any month but i am stucked with a date range.

kindly help, it will be highly appreciated.

**Note : I am using Sql 2008 and date rang could be 1 month , 2 month or 6 month or a year or max too..**

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/18/sql-server-find-last-day-of-any-month-current-previous-next/

Comment: just went throgh that...

Comment: what happend using the query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for getting all last days of the month within the defined range

```
Declare @Start datetime
Declare @End datetime

Select @Start = '20130808'
Select @End = '20131111'
;With CTE as
(
Select @Start  as Date,Case When DatePart(mm,@Start)<>DatePart(mm,@Start+1) then 1 else 0 end as [Last]
UNION ALL
Select Date+1,Case When DatePart(mm,Date+1)<>DatePart(mm,Date+2) then 1 else 0 end from CTE
Where Date<@End
)

Select * from CTE
where [Last]=1   OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @tmpTable table (LastDates DATE);
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '01/01/2012'; --1 Jan 2012
DECLARE @endDate DATE = '05/31/2012';   --31 May 2012
DECLARE @tmpEndDate DATE;

SET @startDate = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@startDate)+1,1));
SET @tmpEndDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @endDate);

WHILE (@startDate <= @tmpEndDate)
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO @tmpTable (LastDates) values (DATEADD(DAY, -1, @startDate));
    SET @startDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @startDate);
END

SELECT [LastDates] FROM @tmpTable;
```

**Output:**

**Example: 1**

```
@startDate DATE = '01/01/2012'; --1 Jan 2012
@endDate DATE = '05/31/2012';   --31 May 2012

LastDates
----------
2012-01-31
2012-02-29
2012-03-31
2012-04-30
2012-05-31
```

**Example: 2**

```
@startDate DATE = '11/01/2011'; --1 Nov 2011
@endDate DATE = '03/13/2012';   --13 Mar 2012

LastDates
----------
2011-11-30
2011-12-31
2012-01-31
2012-02-29
```

Comment: Very good performance. It will iterate through only 1 record per month.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a table variable, filled it with all days between `@startDate` and `@endDate` and searched for max date in the month.

```
declare @tmpTable table (dates date)
declare @startDate date = '08/08/2013'
declare @endDate date = '11/11/2013'

while @startDate <= @endDate
begin
    insert into @tmpTable (dates) values (@startDate)
    set @startDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startDate)
end

select max(dates) as [Last day] from @tmpTable as o
group by datepart(YEAR, dates), datepart(MONTH, dates)
```

Results:

```
Last day
2013-08-31
2013-09-30
2013-10-31
2013-11-11
```

To also get last day of November this can be used before loop:

```
set @endDate = DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @endDate) + 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Following script demonstrates the script to find last day of previous, current and next month.

```
----Last Day of Previous Month
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
LastDay_PreviousMonth
----Last Day of Current Month
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
LastDay_CurrentMonth
----Last Day of Next Month
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+2,0))
LastDay_NextMonth
```

If you want to find last day of month of any day specified use following script.

```
--Last Day of Any Month and Year
DECLARE @dtDate DATETIME
SET @dtDate = '8/18/2007'
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dtDate)+1,0))
LastDay_AnyMonth
ResultSet:
LastDay_AnyMonth
```

Source - SQL Server Central.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE to do this, note the `MAXRECURSION` `OPTION` prevents an infinite loop:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2013-08-08'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2013-11-11'

;WITH dateCTE
AS
(
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(M, 1,DATEADD(d, DAY(@StartDate) * -1, @StartDate)) AS DATE) EndOFMonth
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(M, 2,DATEADD(d, DAY(EndOFMonth) * -1, EndOFMonth)) AS DATE) 
    FROM dateCTE
    WHERE EndOFMonth < DATEADD(d, DAY(@EndDate) * -1, @EndDate)

)
SELECT *
FROM dateCTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 30);
```

This returns

```
EndOFMonth
----------
2013-08-31
2013-09-30
2013-10-31
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
the last row(where) is optional for date filtering

```
declare @table table  
(  
thisdate date  
)


insert into @table values ('12/01/2013'),('05/06/2013'),('04/29/2013'),('02/20/2013')
select *,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,thisdate)+1,0))
LastDay from @table
where thisdate between 'givendate' and 'givendate'
```

The Example Below is for all dates

```
thisdate    lastday
2013-12-01  2013-12-31 23:59:59.000
2013-05-06  2013-05-31 23:59:59.000
2013-04-29  2013-04-30 23:59:59.000
2013-02-20  2013-02-28 23:59:59.000
```

Answer (score 0):

The following CTE gives you the last day of every month from February 1900 until the middle of the 26th century (on my machine):

```
;with LastDaysOfMonths as (
    select DATEADD(month,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY so.object_id),
                 '19000131') as Dt
    from sys.objects so,sys.objects so1
)
select * from LastDaysOfMonths
```

It should be easy enough to use it as part of a larger query or to filter it down to just the dates you want. You can adjust the range of years as needed by changing the constant `19000131`. The only important thing to do is make sure that you use a month that has 31 days in it and always have the constant be for day 31.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a common table expression or anything like that - this simple query will do it:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, DATEADD(m, number, '2013-08-08')) + 1, 0)) AS EndOfMonth
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE   'P' = type
        AND DATEADD(m, number, '2013-08-08') < '2013-11-11';
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is about the last day which @bummi has already answered.

But here is the solution for the first date which might be helpful for someone.

**Get the first dates of all the months in-between the `@FromDate` and `@ToDate`.**

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = '2019-08-13'
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME = '2019-11-25'

;WITH CTE
AS 
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@FromDate) - 1), @FromDate) AS FirstDateOfMonth

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, FirstDateOfMonth)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE FirstDateOfMonth < DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@ToDate) - 1), @ToDate)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Here is the result

```
--Result
2019-08-01 00:00:00.000
2019-09-01 00:00:00.000
2019-10-01 00:00:00.000
2019-11-01 00:00:00.000
```