# MAX statement in SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have two lists of contracts  One has past ending dates for each. Each time the ending date gets updated or extended a new record is createed in the original table.  The other just has the contract number and product description.  The first looks like this:

```
Contract   End Date
AAA001     12/01/2013 
AAA001     12/30/2013
BBB002     01/01/2014
BBB002     01/30/2014
```

You can see that for each contract the end date was updatedonce each.

```
Contract   Product
AAA001     Apples
AAA001     Apples
BBB002     Oranges
BBB002     Oranges
```

I need a query that will produce a table like this where only the maximum date value is returned.

```
Contract   Product   End Date
AAA001     Apples    12/30/2013
BBB002     Oranges   01/30/2014
```

Is it possible to use a Mas...In statement?  I am using Access 2010.

Comment: use GROUP BY to achieve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query

```
Select Contract, product, MAX(endDate) FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.contract = table2.contract 
group by contract, product
```

Comment: Sorry it's still returning all the different dates with just the products added.

Comment: Ah, I see now, I'll try to give you a better example the next chance I get. I believe you will need something like a Common Table Expression, such as http://stackoverflow.com/a/18869541/1504882

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing that out.  I will mess around with that once I get back to work.  That example is pushing the limits of my SQL knowledge,  Will see if I can get it to work!

Comment: @user2907249 did you ever get this to work? Could you show me what the SQL above returned that was wrong?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  go it to work.  I just created a crosstab query and then pulled then end dates from there.  Makes it a bit less efficient but the dataset is not so large that it matters much.

Comment: Could you show that in an edit on your question for future users?